# AG-Grid - Any way to have a pinned column fill the remaining space of the grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I know that I can use the `flex` attribute on a column def if I want that column to take up the remaining space of a grid, like this:

```
  public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    { field: 'name',  flex: 1 },
    { field: 'medals.gold', headerName: 'Gold' },
    { field: 'person.age' },
  ];
```

And I know that I can pin a column to the left (or right) so that it doesn't scroll with the rest of the columns:

```
  public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    { field: 'name',  pinned: 'left' },
    { field: 'medals.gold', headerName: 'Gold' },
    { field: 'person.age' },
  ];
```

But I have a case where I want the first column to both be pinned AND fill the remaining space:

```
  public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    { field: 'name',  flex: 1, pinned: 'left' },
    { field: 'medals.gold', headerName: 'Gold' },
    { field: 'person.age' },
  ];
```

And when I do this (pinned + flex) the grid seems to ignore the flex attribute and always renders the column with the default width. I've been through the AG-Grid docs and don't see anything that explicitly says pinning and flex columns are incompatible, but maybe I'm missing it.

Here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mmMNJZgVCDKOJ1yW) to play with.  Try removing the `pinned` attribute to see the flex column work.

Has anyone been able to combine these attributes on one column?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've found a solution.  I'm not sure if this is a workaround, or if this is the way you're supposed to do it, so...

It was a combination of handling the `gridReady` event and calling `Grid API api.sizeColumnsToFit()`.

In my case, I also set the `width` and `suppressSizeToFit=true` for the non-pinned columns.

Updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LFmPqGprpwVswVF9).